# Have no idea why the listener is not being called in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Heres the event:

```
<?php

namespace App\Modules\Clinicians\Events;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class CreateHealthCareProviderEvent
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
}
```

The event gets called just fine. But the listener:

```
<?php

namespace App\Modules\Clinicians\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\Modules\Clinicians\Events\CreateHealthCareProviderEvent;
use App\Modules\Clinicians\Events\EmailClinicAdminsEvent;
use App\Modules\Users\Services\RegisterUserService;

class CreateHealthCareProviderListener
{

    private $registerUserService;

    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(RegisterUserService $registerUserService)
    {
        $this->registerUserService = $registerUserService;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  object  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(CreateHealthCareProviderEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $this->registerUserService->setRequestData($event->data)->registerUser(Clinic::find($event->data['clinic_id']));

        $user->clinician()->create([
            'user_id'   => $user->id,
        ]);

        $user->clinician->clinics()->attach($event->data['clinic_id']);

        event(new EmailClinicAdminsEvent($user, $event->data['clinic_id']));
    }
}
```

Never gets called. Ever. So how am I registering these?

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],

        // When a new health care provider registers:
        CreateHealthCareProviderEvent::class => [
            CreateHealthCareProviderListener::class,
        ],

        // Email the Clinic admins when a healthcare provider registers:
        // Called in the CreateHealthCareProviderListener handler method.
        EmailClinicAdminsEvent::class => [
            EmailClinicAdminsListener::class,
        ],
    ];

    ...
}
```

I have never had an issue registering events and listeners like this before. They always work. But for some reason the listener will not fire for this event. The event fires just fine. But not the listener. What am I missing?

I have tried:

- `php artisan optimize`
- `composer dump-autoload`

Nothing.

Its called as such:

```
    // Create the health care provider user:
    event(new CreateHealthCareProviderEvent($request->all()));
```

Any ideas? I checked spelling and namespaces and everything seems correct. What am I missing?

There are no errors, nothing. The tests still pass (I dont fake events) and the test coverage shows the event gets called, but the test coverage shows the listener does not get called. When I try this out in the browser, no user is created - which is done by the listener.

*All my other events and their associated listeners are called just fine.*

**What is going on?**

Comment: are you aliasing those classes in the `EventServiceProvider`?

Comment: @lagbox No they are brought in using the `use` statement. I do this for all my events and listeners, these are the only ones who's listeners are not being called.

Comment: gotcha, the `use` statement is aliasing ... just wanted to make sure it was the correct class being referenced as that would be the number one reason for an event not matching up to a listener

Comment: Maybe an opcode cache issue?

Comment: Don't use  opcode cache @AkenRoberts

Comment: @lagbox If the class could not be found would I not receive an error?

Comment: Nothing stands out as incorrect in your code. You aren't queuing listeners, right?

Comment: @AkenRoberts No they are not queued. The only thing that could have caused an issue is I was not importing the Clinic Model. But I wouldn't know that because the listener is never called. Is this an issue with 6.2? Couldn't be, my other events and listers are being called else where.

Comment: if you were referencing the wrong event class then the correct one wouldn't be mapped to a listener .. that is why i was looking to see how the classes were referenced in that file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I am retarded and will take the downvotes on this one but for future reference, make sure your use statements are proper. because Laravel won't tell you when registering events:

```
use App\Modules\Clinicians\CreateHealthCareProviderEvent;
use App\Modules\Clinicians\EmailClinicAdminsEvent;
use App\Modules\Clinicians\CreateHealthCareProviderListener;
use App\Modules\Clinicians\EmailClinicAdminsListener;
```

What do you think is missing here? let me tell you:

```
use App\Modules\Clinicians\Events\CreateHealthCareProviderEvent;
use App\Modules\Clinicians\Events\EmailClinicAdminsEvent;
use App\Modules\Clinicians\Listeners\CreateHealthCareProviderListener;
use App\Modules\Clinicians\Listeners\EmailClinicAdminsListener;
```

This is why the event was being called but not the listener. In the controller class where the event in question was being called, I imported the event properly, but in the event service provider I did not.

Comment: this is why you have to provide the `use` statements in the code so others can verify that, instead of taking your word for it :)

Comment: +1 lagbox upvote. Also, if you aren't using an IDE such as PhpStorm, I definitely suggest moving to one! They'll help point out things like this.

Comment: @TheWebs no downvotes required, you answered your own question, wish that happened more often :p

Comment: I don't know if retarded is a very nice term to use in this context.